# Remove, Clear or Update Widgets Defined Programmatically in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have created a set of buttons whose parent layouts are a gridlayout and scrollview, respectively. I can not find a way to remove the gridlayout or the scrollview so that I may programmatically recreate them and add another set of buttons in the place of the previous set.

I have tried self.remove_widget(layout) but that has not worked.

```
def create_scrollview(self, dt):
    namelist = ["Name", "Age", "Sex", "Height", "Weight"]
    n = 0
    layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=15, size_hint_y=None, padding=40)
    self.ids['grid'] = weakref.ref(layout)
    layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter("height"))
    keys = f(dm.read_name())
    values = dm.read_all()
    temp_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
    if self.name_instance in temp_dict:
        for element in temp_dict[self.name_instance]:
            layout.add_widget(Button(
                on_release=partial(self.nav_to_char_profile),
                text=str(namelist[n])+": "+str(element),
                font_size=25,
                size=(50, 50), size_hint=(1, None),
                background_normal='normal.png',
                background_down='down.png'))
            self.ids["btn"+str(n)] = partial(weakref.ref)
            n = n+1

    layout.add_widget(Button(on_press=partial(self.nav_to_char_profile), text="Back", font_size=25, size=(50, 50),
                             size_hint=(.50, None),
                             background_normal='normal.png',
                             background_down='down.png'))
    scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
    scrollview.add_widget(layout)
    self.ids.container.add_widget(scrollview)
```

method that removes and recreates scrollview:

```
    def return_btn_text(self, instance):
        self.store_text_instance(instance)
        self.remove_widget(App.get_running_app().root.ids.BasicProfile.ids.container)
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.BasicProfile.trigger()
```

Comment: Post a minimal *runnable* example. The code pasted here doesn't even attempt to remove the layout.

Comment: I have added the method I wrote that was supposed to remove and recreate the scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can clear the scrollview before recreating it with:

```
App.get_running_app().root.ids.BasicProfile.ids.container.clear_widgets()
```

`container` being the scrollview id